# Parse c style nested struct using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse c struct using python.
*https://github.com/fox-it/dissect.cstruct/blob/master/dissect/cstruct/cstruct.py#L371*

Regex:
`r'(#(?P<flags>(?:compile))\s+)?((?P<typedef>typedef)\s+)?(?P<type>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<name>[^\s]+)?(?P<fields>\s*\{[^}]+\}(?P<defs>\s+[^;\n]+)?)?\s*;'`

It works perfectly fine with simple struct but does not work with nested struct.

Works fine:

```
typedef struct test {
    char    magic[4];
    wchar   wmagic[4];
    uint8   a;
    uint16  b;
    uint32  c;
    char    string[];
     wchar   wstring[];
} test_;
```

Fails:

```
typedef struct test {
        char    magic[4];
        wchar   wmagic[4];
        uint8   a;
        uint16  b;
        uint32  c;
        char    string[];
        wchar   wstring[];
        struct { 
            int a;
        } item[20];
} test_;
```

In first case it defs has value test_ but in second case defs is item.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot parse languages with arbitrary nesting depths.

Comment: You are right. I replaced regex with loop and custom string matching logic.